# Connect to SQL server via ssh tunnel (ngrok)

Tags: electron, sql-server-2000, ngrok

I'm making an electron JS app which connects to sql server 2000 using msnodesqlv8. Everything is working fine using localhost but i want to connect to it using a tunnel. I'm trying to use ngrok.
This is my connection string:

```
"Driver={SQL Server};Server={ngrok_tunnel_url};Database={DBname};Uid={sa};Pwd={root};Trusted_Connection={No};"
```

It works when i pass localhost to server in connection string but when i pass it with a port(1433) it doesn't work.
Maybe i'm doing something wrong. can anyone please guide a little bit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did ya make any further progress on your question?

Taking a look at the connection string you posted:

```js
"Driver={SQL Server};Server={ngrok_tunnel_url};Database={DBname};Uid={sa};Pwd={root};Trusted_Connection={No};"
```

&looking at the library source example:

https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8/wiki#sequelize-compatibility

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

let sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'mssql',
  dialectModulePath: 'msnodesqlv8/lib/sequelize',
  dialectOptions: {
    'user': '',
    'password': '',
    'database': 'scratch',
    'connectionString': 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server= np:\\\\.\\pipe\\LOCALDB#2DD5ECA9\\tsql\\query;Database=scratch;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    'options': {
      'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
      'trustedConnection': true,
      'instanceName': ''
    }
  },
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    idle: 10000
  }
})
```

I would try testing an update in your connection string:

`Trusted_Connection=no` to `Trusted_Connection=yes`

then see what happens : - )